# Registering plugin in phonegap results in process unexpectedly exiting

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I don't know why it's not working, but when I try to add a plugin for phonegap in android the emulator says process unexpectedly exited. These are the steps I followed:

1. Create a java class for examply MyPlugin that extends Plugin class
2. Create a javascript file that creates a variable which has some function property that calls PhoneGap.exec with appropriate parameter
3. Add `<plugin>` tag with appropriate name and value
4. Run project

Comment: usually phonegap shows some errors which can be ignored but since you application quits it can not be ignored. hope you have followed the steps given here http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android and also the .jar and and .js file are of the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the javascript code was undefined because I wasn't adding the plugin correctly. Had to instantiate the plugin class.